# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data on production environnement

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

i'm working on a web application with laravel and i made a "project space" for users. in this "project space" i have to display a table of files for each folder of the "project" so i used Ajax to change the content of the table,but this work fine on my localhost but it doesn't on online server.

i made a controller that returns data in json and the Ajax code will change the html and display files of the selected folder. so this is the ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
            type    :"get",
            url     :"/bibliotheque/Projet/ajax_liste_maquettes  /"+id_projet, 
            data: { id_projet:id_projet },
            success :function(data) {
              var b="1";
            //  document.getElementById('titreid').text = tableau[4];
            $('#records_table').empty();
            document.getElementById("records_table").innerHTML = "<table border = '1'>" +
            '<tr>' +
            '<th width="13%">Action</th>'+
            '<th>Nom</th>'+ 
            '<th>Date</th>'+
            '<th>Ajouter par</th>' +
            '<th>Fonction</th>' +
            '</tr>';  
             $.each(data.response, function(i, item) {
              chaine = ""+data.response[i].id_projet+"-"+data.response[i].id+"-"+data.response[i].url+"-"+ data.response[i].nom_fichier;
                  $('<tr>').html(
                      "<td>" +  
                         '<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://nebnibim.dz'+ '/bibliotheque/Projet/download/'+data.response[i].id+'" target="_blank" class="embed"   > <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>'  

                        +'<a href="'+ '/bibliotheque/Projet/download/'+data.response[i].id+'" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'
                        +'<a href="'+baseUrl+'bibliotheque/Projet/deletFchier/'+data.response[i].id+'"  onclick=\"return(confirm(\'Etes-vous sur de vouloir supprimer ce fichier\'));\"> <i class="fa fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'  
                     + "</td>"+
              "<td onclick=\"fichierTaches('"+chaine+"')\">" +    data.response[i].nom_fichier +"."+data.response[i].format +"</td><td>" + data.response[i].created_at + "</td><td>" + data.response[i].nom_collaborateur +"</td><td>"+data.response[i].collaboration + "</td>").appendTo('#records_table');
              });
```

this code display the file's table and it work fine in localhost but in the web server online it doesn't when i check the network section i see this error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

Comment: Can you add `dataType: 'json',` in ajax params and try again?

Comment: Also `id_projet` is already present in the URL as route param, then you can use that instead of passing it again in ajax data.

Comment: Can you show what data your server return in production environment? Also how do you print the json in your backend?

Comment: i already tried to add dataType: 'json' and i tried also to keep th id_projet just in the url but nothing changes

Comment: here is what i have in the response tab of the network tab i don't know why i have the "." before :
.{"response":[{"id":181,"id_projet":114,"role":"admin","id_collaborateur":408,"created_at":"2019-01-03 08:06:57","updated_at":"2019-01-03 08:06:57"}]}